# Disable certificate verification on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have one very old legacy project, its web API, and really I need to call it (it hosts on Windows Server 2012). This API require **.p12** premade client certificates include in request to it, and i have one.

It works only with https and it have strange certificate.

If i debug my `.net 6` project (calls with `RestSharp`) on Windows 10 - it's OK, but on `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` I have issues.

Adding `TLSv1.0` or `TLSv1.1` or `TLSv1.2` support in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` don't works.

Curl -k or --insecure don't works.

```
root@nginx:/home/xxx# curl -vvv  https://192.168.201.111:44301/api/
*   Trying 192.168.201.111:44301...
* Connected to 192.168.201.111 (192.168.201.111) port 44301 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
* error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
```

And else:

```
root@nginx:/home/xxx# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.201.111:44301
CONNECTED(00000003)
40A77EF2787F0000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1952:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 58 bytes and written 300 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Please help me disable this cert validation.

**UPD**

In C# I do something like this to configure RestClient (on windows it works fine, but on ubuntu it fails):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls; 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, ce, ca, p) => true;
FileInfo certFile = new (certFileName);
if (certFile.Exists is false) throw new FileNotFoundException("Certificate file not found");
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(certFile.FullName, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true;

var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl)
{
    FollowRedirects = true,
    ClientCertificates = certificates,
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
};
Client = new RestClient(options);
```

**UPD2**

```
root@nginx:/home/xxx# openssl s_client -tls1 -cipher 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1'  -connect 192.168.201.111:44301
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 CN = ORGANIZATION
verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=1 CN = ORGANIZATION
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = OFFICE1
verify return:1
405744F5247F0000:error:0A0C0103:SSL routines:tls_process_key_exchange:internal error:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2248:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = OFFICE1
   i:CN = ORGANIZATION
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 1024 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA512
   v:NotBefore: Sep 26 12:10:32 2018 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 23 12:10:32 2028 GMT
 1 s:CN = ORGANIZATION
   i:CN = ORGANIZATION
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 1024 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA1
   v:NotBefore: Sep 26 12:10:29 2018 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 23 12:10:29 2028 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(i replace cert with *)
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = OFFICE1
issuer=CN = ORGANIZATION
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1657 bytes and written 111 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1654443076
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: This doesn't look like SSL validation. Instead your server is so old that it starts with an SSLv3 handshake. As SSLv3 has been eliminated from nearly all security libraries in the last years the handshake fails. You should better try to modify the legacy project to provide at least TLS1.0 handshake and connection, then your problems are solved. Or if you can't checke the old project let it only listen on localhost for unencrypted HTTP and use a Nginx server as HTTPS frontend forwarding everything to the actual server.

Comment: There is no "ssl validation" but only "certificate validation". And this error is not related to this validation but about TLS protocol versions. Try to enforce TLS 1.0 with `openssl s_client -tls1 -cipher 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1' ...`

Comment: @Robert this legacy isn't opensource, so i can't fix it.

Comment: Even if it is not opensource there are often ways to reconfigure it (e.g. if it is on Java configure the JRE). Check also my updated comment on the Nginx HTTPS frontend.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich please check *upd2*, can i add this cert to trusted, and how? Thank you!

Comment: @hamaronooo: *"can i add this cert to trusted,"* - this is a  different question. But in short: get the CA and add it with the `-CAfile` argument. And you also need to give your client certificate (`openssl s_client -cert cert.p12 -inform p12 ...`)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Please provide the full answer, I will mark it with green check :)

Comment: @Robert unfortunately, this legacy API works only with `https`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ... routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol: ...
> ...
> ```
>
> Please help me disable this cert validation.

The error is not related to certificate validation but is about TLS protocol versions. One can enforce TLS 1.0 with

```
openssl s_client -tls1 -cipher 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1' ...
```

> This API require .p12 premade client certificates include in request to it, and i have one.

You need to add the client certificate too:

```
openssl s_client -cert cert.p12 -inform p12 ...
```

> ```
> verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
> ```

You need to add the CA with

```
openssl s_client -CAfile ca.pem ...
```

The CA is not send by the server though so you have to ask whoever is responsible in order to get the CA.

Comment: I got `.crt` certificate file from server file system :) Please, can you finish -CAfile command, I can't understand. Thanks.

Comment: @hamaronooo: Extensions don't matter. Check the contents of the file for something like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE ---`. If it is there, then it is PEM format, no matter what extension it has.

Comment: Yes, current `.crt` file have those lines. So, how I should add certificate to trusted? Please, complete your command. `openssl s_client -CAfile /var/mycert.crt ...` <3

Comment: @hamaronooo: If mycert.crt is the CA which issued the server certificate, then this is the correct way to trust it.